# Why can’t vulkan subpass contents be both inline and secondary command buffers?

Tags: vulkan

Just out of curiosity, because this has caused some annoyance, I cannot think of a reason for why vulkan subpass contents need to be either one (inline) or the other (secondary command buffers). Why not both?? I’ve looked through the doc, perhaps I missed something...